# Rust - Same Type different behaviour

Tags: generics, rust, box

As far as my understanding goes, generics allow the same behavior to be shared among different types. For instances,

```
trait Bird {}

struct BirdFly {}

impl Bird for BirdFly  {
   pub fn fly() -> can fly
}

struct BirdCantFly {}

impl Bird for BirdCantFly{
   pub fn fly() -> can't fly
}

let birds = vec![
    Box::new(BirdFly{}),        // allow this bird to fly, for instance
    Box::new(BirdCantFly{}),    // don't allow this bird to fly
];
```

My question is about the other way around, i.e., is it possible to make the same type take different behaviors (without ifs, enums, nor Box).In this example, it seems a waste to have a Box, BirdFly and BirdCantFly when in both types (BirdFly and BirdCantFly) the dimension is the same, only the behavior is different.

Something like:

```
struct Bird {
   fly: // associate different behavior
}

let birds = vec![
    Bird{ fly: some_fly_behavior },      // allow this bird to fly, for instance
    Bird{ fly: another_fly_behavior },   // don't allow this bird to fly
];

birds[0].fly();
birds[1].fly();
```

if fly receives the same arguments and returns the same type I can't see a reason for the issue. Furthermore, this way I could get rid of the Box inside the vector. Especially because I may have millions of elements inside the vector and are accessed multiple times iteratively and this way I would avoid the overhead.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store [function pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-pointer.html) inside the `struct Bird` and add a helper method to get the syntax you want.

```rust
struct Bird {
    name: String,
    fly_impl: fn(&Bird) -> (),
}

impl Bird {
    fn new(name: String, fly_impl: fn(&Bird) -> ()) -> Bird {
        Bird { name, fly_impl }
    }

    fn fly(self: &Bird) {
        (self.fly_impl)(self)
    }
}

fn behavior1(b: &Bird) {
    println!("{} behavior1", b.name);
}

fn behavior2(b: &Bird) {
    println!("{} behavior2", b.name);
}

fn main() {
    let captured_variable = 10;
    let birds = vec![
        Bird::new("Bird1".into(), behavior1),
        Bird::new("Bird2".into(), behavior2),
        Bird::new("Bird3".into(), |b| println!("{} lambda", b.name)),
        /*Bird::new("Bird4".into(), |b| {
            println!("{} lambda with {}", b.name, captured_variable)
        }),*/
    ];
    (birds[0].fly_impl)(&birds[0]);
    for bird in birds {
        bird.fly();
    }
}
```

`fn` is not to be confused with `trait Fn`. The former allows for functions and non-capturing lambdas only and has fixed size. The latter allows for arbitrary captures of arbitrary size, hence requiring some indirection like `Box`. Both do dynamic dispatch when called.

Note how `Bird3`'s behavior is specified by a non-capturing lambda, this is allowed.
However, if you try to uncomment `Bird4`, the example won't compile as its desired behavior is a capturing lambda, which can grow arbitrary big in general and we've banned `Box`es together with other indirection.

I don't know enough Rust to tell you whether there is a more Rust-like solution. However, your situation is quite specific:

- You have an arbitrary extendable hierarchy of `Bird`s. Otherwise `enum` fits much better.
- However, all `Bird`s in this hierarchy have exactly the same set of fields and `trait`s supported. Otherwise, you have to use `trait`s and standard dynamic dispatch via `Box<dyn Bird>`.
- You don't want heap allocation for individual `Bird`s. Otherwise, you may use `trait`s and standard dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Thank you @yeputons. Your answer was very useful. It turns out that now the compiler is now complaining about the derive Debug that I have above the Bird struct (I didn't have included it in the example above). Do you know of any solution for that too? Thank you so much!